# SQL comparing two sets of complex data

Tags: sql, ms-access, compare

Sorry, probably the title is not the best one but I hope you will understand what problem I have.

I need to compare and analyse two sets of data and I'm using MS-Access for that. My data is organized in two tables. Following is not the real data I'm working with but will serve ok as example:

TABLE 1

```
ID  Name
1   Zoie
2   Rohan
2   Simon
3   Jerome
4   Jakob
4   Mathew
4   Cora
6   Keely
7   Aiyana
7   Jake
8   Reid
9   Emerson
```

TABLE 2

```
ID  Name
1   Michael
2   Rohan
2   Simon
3   Jill
4   Jakob
4   Cora
5   Charlie
7   John
8   Reid
9   Yadiel
9   Emerson
9   Paris
```

1. So, I need to select only those IDs which fully corresponds (all names under specific IDs are the same) in both tables and those are: 2 and 8
2. I would also like to have separate select statement which will result with IDs 2 and 8 but also IDs with names from table 1 which also appears in table 2 (all from table 1 plus possible some extra in table 2 under the same ID). So that would be: 2, 8, 9
3. I would also like to have separate select statement which will result with IDs 2 and 8 but also IDs with names from table 2 which also appears in table 1 (all from table 2 plus possible some extra in table 1 under the same ID). So that would be: 2, 4, 8
4. I would also like to have separate select statement which would be a combination of last two.
   So result would be: 2, 4, 8, 9

I would appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks in advance!
Best regards,
Mario

Comment: what have you tried so far? any issues you get?

Comment: I simply don't know how to make this sql statement and don't know how to express myself while searching on web for a solution. If I would be able to find some similar example I believe I would be able to apply it to my example.

Comment: Homework assignment, right?  What type of answer are you supposed to provide?  Just a finished list?  SQL? VBA? A complete database?  What did the earlier parts of the chapter cover?  (I wouldn't exactly call a list of names "complex data"!)

Comment: part of the learning process is to try it yourself. you will get more confidence when you start doing it and achieve something on your own. it is not easy but look at nike. just do it.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions. Actually it is not for homework but for a real job. I know some really basic SQL but I'm not programmer or advanced DB user and I don't do this every day. I mostly use MS office tools when need to do something like this (excel and access) but usually I have to compare data 1:1 across the tables so I didn't know how to approach this problem. I needed this analysis as a small part of a bigger job (to get the insight into the data and make some decisions about further steps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q#1:

```
select id
from table1
group by id
having count(*) =
(
  select count(*)
  from table2
  group by table2.id
  having table2.id = table1.id
) 
and count(*) = 
(
  select count(*)
  from table1 table1_1
  inner join table2 on table1_1.id = table2.id and table1_1.name = table2.name
  group by table1_1.id
  having table1_1.id = table1.id
)
```

Explanation of this query:

- It is grouping table1 by ID
- For each group (for each ID), it is counting the number of rows in table1 that have this ID.
- For each group, it is counting the number of rows in table2 that have this ID.
- For each group, it is counting the number of rows where the name appears in both tables for this ID (it does that by `inner join`ing table1 and table2 on the ID and Name which means only rows where both ID and Name match in both tables will be counted, for each ID).
- It then returns IDs (from table1) where each of the above counts are equal. This is what results in returning IDs where all names are in both tables (no more, no less).

Q#2 - In this case you don't care that table2 has the same number of names per ID. So remove the first sub-query (that counts matching rows in table2).

```
select id
from table1
group by id
having count(*) = 
(
  select count(*)
  from table1 table1_1
  inner join table2 on table1_1.id = table2.id and table1_1.name = table2.name
  group by table1_1.id
  having table1_1.id = table1.id
)
```

Although the above is easy enough to understand following the same logic as Q#1, it is probably more efficient to do the following, and more straightforward. It only matters if you find it running too slow for your data (which is subjective and context dependent).

```
select table1.id
from table1
left join table2 on table1.id = table2.id and table1.name = table2.name
group by table1.id
having count(table1.id) = count(table2.id)
```

Here, the two tables are `LEFT` (outer) joined which means all records from table1 are gathered and records in table2 that match by ID and Name are also included alongside. Then, we group them by ID and we compare the count of each group in table1 with those that had matching names in table2.

Q#3 - This case is the same as Q#2 except table1 and table2 are swapped.

Q#4 - In this case you only care about IDs that have at least one name that appears in both tables. So join the tables and return the distinct IDs:

```
select distinct id
from table1 
inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id and table1.name = table2.name
```

Here is a SQLFiddle to play with containing the four queries: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3fc71/22

Comment: Andrew, thank you very much for your effort (for providing me with example and explanation)! It works great! It is little slow on my computer and tables with 65000 rows but this is one-time analysis so it is no problem to wait for half an houre.

Comment: I edited the answer with more details (instead of just hints) after finding out you weren't doing homework :).

Comment: Thanks again! I saved your whole answer as a cookbook for any similar future tasks. Also nice tip for this sqlfiddle!

Comment: I added a probably-faster version of Q2.